# What is the general expression for the number of possible way to generate $k$ distinct number from $n$ sequentially?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation

What is the general expression for the number of possible way to generate $k$ distinct number from $n$ sequentially?

For example, let's say I have $n$ numbers ranging from $1$ to $9$ and I want to select $k=5$ distinct numbers from these nine numbers sequentially.

Assume the selections are

- $(1,2,3,4,5)$
- $(2,3,4,5,6)$
- $(3,4,5,6,7)$
- $(4,5,6,7,8)$
- $(5,6,7,8,9)$

I want to know the **general formula** to express this.

I am guessing this is a coupon collector problem and If I use this formula for the expected number of outcome
$$E = n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$$
E will equal $\approx{25}$, which means that for example $(1,2,3,4,5)$ and $(5,4,3,2,1)$ are seen as different sequences, but in my case, both of them are the same (distinct).

Comment: The question is really only how to select a number between one and five, as all number after are not random at all. Or is the question, what is the probability to select five numbers such that they are ordered? In that case it would be hypergeometric, ie $\frac{5}{9*8*7*6*4}$ as all numbers (might) be selected with equal probability? Maybe you can give the original question?

Comment: "For example, let's say I have n numbers ranging from 1-9 and I want to select k=5 distinct numbers from these nine numbers sequentially." I do not understand what Math problem that you are trying to solve.  Please proofread your posting, asking yourself whether it is possible, in your mind, whether someone would be confused about what you are asking.  Then, try to edit your posting to make it impossible for there to be any confusion.

Comment: If you are asking for number of convex subsequences of length $k$ from an ordered set of size $n$ [i.e. the value you want for $n=9$ and $k=5$ is $E=5$], then the answer is simply $E = n - k + 1$, since there's one such sequence starting with each of $1, 2, ..., n-k+1$. But maybe that's not what you mean?

Comment: @Ned, that's exactly what I meant. Thank you for this. However, as another related question, what is the expected number of draws required to draw k sequence of numbers from n without replacement?

Answer (score 1):

The number of ways to select $k$ distinct objects from $n$ distinct objects is simply
$${n \choose k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

In your case, the answer would be
$${9 \choose 5} = 126$$

The following are all $126$ possible selections:

$(1,2,3,4,5)$,
$(1,2,3,4,6)$,
$(1,2,3,4,7)$,
$(1,2,3,4,8)$,
$(1,2,3,4,9)$,
$(1,2,3,5,6)$,
$(1,2,3,5,7)$,
$(1,2,3,5,8)$,
$(1,2,3,5,9)$,
$(1,2,3,6,7)$,
$(1,2,3,6,8)$,
$(1,2,3,6,9)$,
$(1,2,3,7,8)$,
$(1,2,3,7,9)$,
$(1,2,3,8,9)$,
$(1,2,4,5,6)$,
$(1,2,4,5,7)$,
$(1,2,4,5,8)$,
$(1,2,4,5,9)$,
$(1,2,4,6,7)$,
$(1,2,4,6,8)$,
$(1,2,4,6,9)$,
$(1,2,4,7,8)$,
$(1,2,4,7,9)$,
$(1,2,4,8,9)$,
$(1,2,5,6,7)$,
$(1,2,5,6,8)$,
$(1,2,5,6,9)$,
$(1,2,5,7,8)$,
$(1,2,5,7,9)$,
$(1,2,5,8,9)$,
$(1,2,6,7,8)$,
$(1,2,6,7,9)$,
$(1,2,6,8,9)$,
$(1,2,7,8,9)$,
$(1,3,4,5,6)$,
$(1,3,4,5,7)$,
$(1,3,4,5,8)$,
$(1,3,4,5,9)$,
$(1,3,4,6,7)$,
$(1,3,4,6,8)$,
$(1,3,4,6,9)$,
$(1,3,4,7,8)$,
$(1,3,4,7,9)$,
$(1,3,4,8,9)$,
$(1,3,5,6,7)$,
$(1,3,5,6,8)$,
$(1,3,5,6,9)$,
$(1,3,5,7,8)$,
$(1,3,5,7,9)$,
$(1,3,5,8,9)$,
$(1,3,6,7,8)$,
$(1,3,6,7,9)$,
$(1,3,6,8,9)$,
$(1,3,7,8,9)$,
$(1,4,5,6,7)$,
$(1,4,5,6,8)$,
$(1,4,5,6,9)$,
$(1,4,5,7,8)$,
$(1,4,5,7,9)$,
$(1,4,5,8,9)$,
$(1,4,6,7,8)$,
$(1,4,6,7,9)$,
$(1,4,6,8,9)$,
$(1,4,7,8,9)$,
$(1,5,6,7,8)$,
$(1,5,6,7,9)$,
$(1,5,6,8,9)$,
$(1,5,7,8,9)$,
$(1,6,7,8,9)$,
$(2,3,4,5,6)$,
$(2,3,4,5,7)$,
$(2,3,4,5,8)$,
$(2,3,4,5,9)$,
$(2,3,4,6,7)$,
$(2,3,4,6,8)$,
$(2,3,4,6,9)$,
$(2,3,4,7,8)$,
$(2,3,4,7,9)$,
$(2,3,4,8,9)$,
$(2,3,5,6,7)$,
$(2,3,5,6,8)$,
$(2,3,5,6,9)$,
$(2,3,5,7,8)$,
$(2,3,5,7,9)$,
$(2,3,5,8,9)$,
$(2,3,6,7,8)$,
$(2,3,6,7,9)$,
$(2,3,6,8,9)$,
$(2,3,7,8,9)$,
$(2,4,5,6,7)$,
$(2,4,5,6,8)$,
$(2,4,5,6,9)$,
$(2,4,5,7,8)$,
$(2,4,5,7,9)$,
$(2,4,5,8,9)$,
$(2,4,6,7,8)$,
$(2,4,6,7,9)$,
$(2,4,6,8,9)$,
$(2,4,7,8,9)$,
$(2,5,6,7,8)$,
$(2,5,6,7,9)$,
$(2,5,6,8,9)$,
$(2,5,7,8,9)$,
$(2,6,7,8,9)$,
$(3,4,5,6,7)$,
$(3,4,5,6,8)$,
$(3,4,5,6,9)$,
$(3,4,5,7,8)$,
$(3,4,5,7,9)$,
$(3,4,5,8,9)$,
$(3,4,6,7,8)$,
$(3,4,6,7,9)$,
$(3,4,6,8,9)$,
$(3,4,7,8,9)$,
$(3,5,6,7,8)$,
$(3,5,6,7,9)$,
$(3,5,6,8,9)$,
$(3,5,7,8,9)$,
$(3,6,7,8,9)$,
$(4,5,6,7,8)$,
$(4,5,6,7,9)$,
$(4,5,6,8,9)$,
$(4,5,7,8,9)$,
$(4,6,7,8,9)$,
$(5,6,7,8,9)$